# Default windows domain for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I want add access for '<domain>\domain users' account on feature installation.

So, may be Sharepoint has 'default' windows domain, which I can use for generate login name?

After installation application will provide possibility for add any other domain, but during install it will be nice to add access for 'default' domain users.

P.S. This is need for add user through SiteUsers.Add('XXX\Domain Users' ...), not by hands.

Sharepoint: WSS 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but when you install SharePoint, it will use Windows Authentication by default.

This means that your SharePoint application will already know about all the domain users. You don't need to generate a login name for then, they will just use their windows login name (and the security will be integrated when they use internet explorer, they will only have to login when they use other browsers.).

You can then set permissions the way you want using NT groups or SharePoint groups or both.

If I didn't understand the question, could you please clarify what you mean by "feature installation"?

Comment: Well. I write some complicated sharepoint solution. When it is installed(or deployed... I am not sure in terminology yet) it should automatically add list, say 'List1', and add permissions for domain users for this list. For this solution installer should add 'XXX\Domain Users' in group 'Contributors'. And here installer need to know real name of domain, because SiteUsers.Add('Domain Users', ...) not work. When I enter this by hand it is work, but I need automated installer. So, I need in runtime discover 'default' domain name if it is possible. And sory for my poor english.